# Pythonic way to import module whose name is only known at runtime?

Tags: python, dynamic, python-module

Given the following folder structure:

```
executioner/:
  - executioner.py
  - library/:
    - __init__.py
    - global_functions.py
    - oakalleyit.py
```

If I wanted to access a function inside of either global_functions.py or oakalleyit.py, but I won't know the name of the function or module until runtime, how would I do it?

Something like:

```
from library import 'oakalleyit'

'oakalleyit'.'cleanup'()
```

Where the `''` implies it came from a config file, CLI argument, etc.

Comment: Your file structure indicates you are trying to access a *module* whose name you don't know (one of the two .py files), not just a function.

Comment: @BrenBarn That is exactly the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access names dynamically; this includes module objects:

```
import library
getattr(library, 'oakalleyit')()
```

Demo with the `hashlib` module:

```
>>> import hashlib
>>> getattr(hashlib, 'md5')()
<md5 HASH object @ 0x1012a02b0>
>>> getattr(hashlib, 'sha1')()
<sha1 HASH object @ 0x1012a03f0>
```

If you need to dynamic module access, you'll need to use the [`importlib.import_module()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module) to import modules based on a string value:

```
from importlib import import_module

module = import_module('library.oakalleyit')
getattr(module, 'some_function_name')()
```

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "executioner.py", line 5, in <module>
    getattr(library, 'oakalleyit')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'oakalleyit'

Comment: Despite what he says, his example suggests he needs to access a dynamically-determined module, not a function.  This won't work unless `library`'s `__init__.py` auto-imports all its submodules.

Comment: @BrenBarn That won't work, multiple files under 'library' may have the same function names that do different things.

Comment: @BrenBarn Sorry, just corrected, meant multiple modules with the same function names.

Comment: I don't think you can use `import_module` that way.  You'll need to do `import_module('library.oakalleyit')` or `import_module('.oakalleyit', 'library')`.

Comment: @BrenBarn: ick, you are indeed correct.